# How to call a method when a Mac wakes up

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

I've got a menubar application that calls for updates periodically. One of the updates is called every 5 minutes. The other is every 1 minute. If I close my laptop and then open it later, I'd like the application to make both of those method calls right away and restart those timers. How can I detect that a Mac has woken up? Is there some Notification Center notification I can listen for? Or perhaps an even cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `NSWorkspace`'s `NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification` notification.

Comment: I attempted this, putting this in one of my implementation files:  
`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self                                  selector:@selector(refreshData)                                     name:NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification
object:nil];`  but it doesn't seem to call that `refreshData` method. Is there more to it than what I did to subscribe to that notification?

Comment: I think I got it. I needed to use `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter]` instead of `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]`